# Same forum in multiple menus?

Tags: routes, path-aliases, uri, nodes

I'm building a site which has several "guide" sections, each with their own menu. Think "London guide", "Paris guide", "Berlin guide" etc.

All of these guides will share the same forum - call it "European city forum". (I don't anticipate there'll be enough postings to merit one forum per guide, at least not at first.)

I'd like this forum to be accessible within each guide section, while retaining the guide menu. So you could click on "forum" from the London menu, or from the Paris menu, and it'd give you the European city forum... **but still within the London or Paris menu.**

In theory I can do this by setting up different URL aliases for the forum (say, `/paris/forum` and `/london/forum`, both leading to `/forum/8`); adding these to each menu; and then checking `request_uri` in my template code, and calling `menu_tree_set_path` accordingly.

However, that only sorts out the menu path and URL for the forum index. Any action that the user takes within that forum, such as viewing a thread or starting a new topic, will go to the standard URL - such as `/node/add/forum/8` - and (therefore) the first matching menu path.

I'd like the user's interactions to continue "within" the city guide that they're browsing. Right now I'm completely stumped as to how to do this.

Any wisdom?